# Solving a double integral using substitution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The problem:

> Evaluate $$\iint_{D}(x+y)^2(x-y)^5\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y,$$ where $D$ is a rectangle with vertices in $(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)$.

So I drew the square and thought up this substitution.

$g(u,v)=(u+v,1-u+v)$. If I integrate that over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ I should get the same square. The jacobian turned out to be $2$. Then, $x=u+v, y=1-u+v$ and $x+y=1+2v, x-y=2u-1$.

If all of this is correct, the integral should be: $$2\int_0^1\int_0^1(1+2v)^3(2u-1)^5\:\mathrm{d}u\:\mathrm{d}v$$ Solving that, the result is $20$. A pretty nice looking number so I thought I must be right. Well, the provided solution disagrees, and is $0$.

They chose a different substitution: $u=x+y, v=y-x$.

Is there something inherently wrong with my substitution?

Comment: I checked what $2\int_0^1\int_0^1(1+2v)^3(2u-1)^5dudv$ should be, it is indeed zero. You made a mistake.

Comment: That's actually great to hear, but I swear I've checked my steps 3 times. Did you check by hand or is there a tool that can solve these things for me?

Comment: Wolfram- Here check this out- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Cint_0%5E1%5Cint_0%5E1%281%2B2v%29%5E3%282u-1%29%5E5dudv

Comment: So WA can take latex input. You learn something every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to substitute like that to see it's $0$.

$D$ is symmetric around the $x=y$ line, but if you exchange $x$ and $y$, the function you integrate changes its sign.

Comment: That's actually really clever.